# Best practis for handling bitmaps in android with mono droid / xamarin.android

Tags: caching, bitmap, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am having some memory issues with our android app when handling bitmaps (duh!).

We are having multiple activities loading images from a server, this could be a background image for the activity.
This background image could be the same for multiple activities, and right now each activity is loading its own background image. 
This means if the flow is ac1->ac2->ac3->ac4 the same image will be loaded 4 times and using 4x memory.

How do I optimize imagehandling for this scenario? Do I create an image cache where the image is stored and then each activity ask the cache first for images. If this is the case, how do I know when to garbage collect the image from the cache?

Any suggestions, link to good tutorials or similar is highly appreciated.

Regards

EDIT:
When downloading images for the device the exact sizes is used, meaning that if the ui element needs an 100x100 pixel image it gets that size and therefore no need for scaling. So i am not sure about downscaling the image when loading it into the memory. Maybe it is needed to unload images in the activity when moving on the the next and then reload when going back.

Comment: You might check out the Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader - probably the best caching solution out there. It also does some smart memory handling. I can upload all the bindings for Xamarin if needed.

Comment: For downscaling the image and to load compressed format you can refer this http://appliedcodelog.blogspot.in/2015/07/avoiding-imagebitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to try is scaling down your bitmaps (make a thumbnail) to a size that is more appropriate to your device. It's pretty easy to quickly use up all the RAM on an Android device with a bitmap if you don't scale it down. This [recipe](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/load_large_bitmaps_efficiently) shows how to do so on the fly. You could adapt this to save the images to disk.

You could also create your own implementation of the [LRUCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) to cache the images for your app.

Comment: This is the most important thing to do when using bitmaps. If you keep them to big you will get an out of memory exception. Also the code on the xamarin site is not complete. You need to sample it down in factors of 2. The code of xamarin can give you a insamplesize of 3 but android will scale that down to 2. That means you'll get a bitmap that is too big. If you need sample code to fix this just let me know.

Comment: Feel free to submit a patch (seriously - we love input from the community).  :)

Comment: Well I dont keep them to big, we download the images for the exact size. So maybe an approach with unloading/reloading images is needed.

Answer (score -1):

After ready your update I will give you an other tip then.
I can still post the patch too if people want that..

What you need to do with those bitmaps is call them with a using block. That way Android will unload the bitmap as soon as that block is executed.

Example:

```
using(Bitmap usedBitmap = new Bitmap()){
     //Do stuff with the Bitmap here
     //You can call usedBitmap.Dispose() but it's not really needed
}
```

With this code your app shouldn't keep all the used bitmaps in memory.

Comment: `//You can call usedBitmap.Dispose() but it's not really needed` Is bad advise because disposing a disposed (implicitly done by `using`) object leads to undefined results.