# Memory efficient bitmap handling in mono for android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I got an application, which allows the user to take a picture. After the picture has been taken, the user can send it to my webserver. But before i do this, it needs to resize the bitmap because i like to have consistent sizes send to my webserver.

Anyway, the code i use to load the bitmap into memory and then manipulate it, does seem to occupy a lot of memory. This code is currently being used :

```
    /*
     *  This method is used to calculate image size.
     *  And also resize/scale image down to 1600 x 1200
     */
    private void ResizeBitmapAndSendToWebServer(string album_id) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
                    // This line is taking up to much memory each time..
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver,fileUri);

                    /*
                     * My question is : Could i do the next image manipulation
                     * before i even load the bitmap into memory?
                     */
        int width = bitmap.Width;
        int height = bitmap.Height;

        if (width >= height) { // <-- Landscape picture

            float scaledWidth = (float)height / width;

            if (width > 1600) {
                bm = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (bitmap, 1600, (int)(1600 * scaledWidth), true);
            } else {
                bm = bitmap;
            }
        } else {

            float scaledHeight = (float)width / height;

            if (height > 1600) {
                bm = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap (bitmap, (int)(1600 * scaledHeight), 1600 , true);
            } else {
                bm = bitmap;
            }

        }
                    // End of question code block.

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ();
        bitmap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 80, stream);
        byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray ();
        bitmap.Dispose ();

        app.api.SendPhoto (Base64.EncodeToString (bitmapData, Base64Flags.Default), album_id);

    }
```

What would be a good and clean way for solving such memory problems?

EDIT 1 :

After reading other posts, it became clear to me that i am doing some inefficient things with my code. This is, in steps, what i have been doing :

1. Load full bitmap into memory.
2. Decide wether it is landscape or not.
3. Then create new bitmap with the right dimensions.
4. Then converting this bitmap into byte array
5. Disposing the initial bitmap. (But never remove the scaled bitmap out of memory).

What i really should be doing :

1. Determine real bitmap dimensions without loading it into memory with :

   ```
   private void FancyMethodForDeterminingImageDimensions() {

       BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
       options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;

       BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileUri.Path, options);

       // Now the dimensions of the bitmap are known without loading
       // the bitmap into memory.
       // I am not further going to explain this, i think the purpose is
       // explaining enough.
       int outWidth = options.OutWidth;
       int outHeight = options.OutHeight;

   }
   ```

> If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the
>   out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the
>   bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

1. Now i know the real dimenions. So i can downsample it before i load it into memory.
2. (in my case) Convert bitmap to base64 string and send it.
3. Dispose everything so the memory gets cleared.

I can't currently test this, because i am not on my development machine. Can anyone give me some feedback if this is the right way? It will be appreciated.

Comment: Cant you do resizing on your server side? You also dont use (or dispose) your `bm` variable, why is that?

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183635/out-of-memory-error-on-setimageresource/16184893#16184893

Comment: @Chintan allthough your method is correct it doesn't allways give the right inSampleSize. See my comment here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319361/best-practis-for-handling-bitmaps-in-android-with-mono-droid-xamarin-android/17330028?noredirect=1#comment25150832_17330028)

Comment: @Cinthan, your code still loads the bitmap into memory. If i do this, it spikes from ~6mb memory to ~42mb. This is a huge difference, and there must be another way of handling this. I would like to know how Google+ and Facebook do their handling after a photo has been taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        private void ResizeBitmapAndSendToWebServer(string album_id) {

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = true; // <-- This makes sure bitmap is not loaded into memory.
            // Then get the properties of the bitmap
            BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (fileUri.Path, options);
            Android.Util.Log.Debug ("[BITMAP]" , string.Format("Original width : {0}, and height : {1}", options.OutWidth, options.OutHeight) );
            // CalculateInSampleSize calculates the right aspect ratio for the picture and then calculate
            // the factor where it will be downsampled with.
            options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize (options, 1600, 1200);
            Android.Util.Log.Debug ("[BITMAP]" , string.Format("Downsampling factor : {0}", CalculateInSampleSize (options, 1600, 1200)) );
            // Now that we know the downsampling factor, the right sized bitmap is loaded into memory.
            // So we set the InJustDecodeBounds to false because we now know the exact dimensions.
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            // Now we are loading it with the correct options. And saving precious memory.
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile (fileUri.Path, options);
            Android.Util.Log.Debug ("[BITMAP]" , string.Format("Downsampled width : {0}, and height : {1}", bm.Width, bm.Height) );
            // Convert it to Base64 by first converting the bitmap to
            // a byte array. Then convert the byte array to a Base64 String.
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream ();
            bm.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 80, stream);
            byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray ();
            bm.Dispose ();

            app.api.SendPhoto (Base64.EncodeToString (bitmapData, Base64Flags.Default), album_id);

        }
```